# Android Studio Custom ArrayAdapter passing HashMap instead of ArrayList

Tags: java, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom adapter that I want to pass a HashMap where Foo is a custom object

```
HashMap<String, Foo> foos = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
//populate foos and pass to adapter
fooAdapter = new FooAdapter(getContext(), foos);
```

My Adapter looks like this

```
public class FooAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Foo> {
    public FooAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, Foo> foos) {
        super(context, R.layout.my_layout, foos);
    }
```

My issue is with passing foos to the base constructor. How can I make it accept a HashMap instead of ArrayList. It works fine if I pass it as an ArrayList, but a HashMap will work better for my application since I am using Firebase and would need the Key at runtime.

Comment: @ScaryWombat nope doesn't seem to be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `ArrayList` that is not possible.

That is because there is no constructor of `ArrayAdapter` that accepts a `HashMap`. If you see the [ArrayAdapter source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) on line 105, you will see it uses a `List<T>` internally to store its items.

If you want to use `HashMap` instead of `List` just create your own `HashMapAdapter` by extended the `BaseAdapter`  similar to the one shown in source code except you replace `List` with a `HashMap` and update this change accordingly through out the code.